# Как работает выпадающее меню на Битрикс?

Tags: php, html, битрикс

Передо мной стоит задача сделать ссылками заголовки с переходом на категорию в выпадающем меню на bitrix, но вообще не понимаю, как работает вывод элементов на битриксе

```
<div class="dropdown__group cf">
                                    <? foreach ($arItem['SUB_MENU'] as $arItem2) : ?>
                                        <?
                                        if (isset($arResult['SECTIONS_IMG'][$arItem2['PARAMS']['ID_SECTION']])) {
                                            $arSectImg[$arResult['SECTIONS_IMG'][$arItem2['ID']]] = $arResult['SECTIONS_IMG'][$arItem2['PARAMS']['ID_SECTION']];
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                        <ul class="dropdown__list">
/*здесь отображаются заголовки внутри меню*/

<li class="dropdown__item dropdown__item-title<? if (count($arItem2['SUB_MENU']) > 1) {?> nohover<?}?>">
                                                    <a <? if (count($arItem2['SUB_MENU']) < 1) {?>
                                                        href = "<?= $arItem2['LINK'];?>"<?}?>><?= $arItem2['TEXT'] ?></a>
                                                </li>
                                                <? if ($arItem2['SUB_MENU']) : ?>
                                                    <? foreach ($arItem2['SUB_MENU'] as $arItem3) : ?>
                                                        <?
                                                        if (isset($arResult['SECTIONS_IMG'][$arItem3['PARAMS']['ID_SECTION']])) {
                                                            $arSectImg[$arResult['SECTIONS_IMG'][$arItem3['ID']]] = $arResult['SECTIONS_IMG'][$arItem3['PARAMS']['ID_SECTION']];
                                                        }
                                                        ?>

/*здесь отображаются заголовки внутри меню*/
/*Здесь отображаются категории меню*/


<li class="dropdown__item"><a
                                                                href="<?= $arItem3['LINK'] ?>"><?= $arItem3['TEXT'] ?></a>
                                                    </li>
                                                <? endforeach ?>
                                            <? endif ?>
                                        </ul>

                                    <? endforeach ?>
                                </div>
```

Comment: не понятна суть вопроса, если уровней мало - раскопируй шаблон horizontal_multilevel

Comment: Вообщем, это dropdown меню, в который элементы выгружаются из БД. Мне нужно, чтобы заголовки, которые находятся в dropdown__item-title вели на категории, тобишь стали ссылками. А вся проблема заключается в том, что не могу понять, как работает вывод элементов из бд на битриксе и следовательно не понимаю, как сделать задачу.

Comment: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=3498&LESSON_PATH=3913.4564.4949.4708.3498 - читать начиная отсюда - "Построение меню из информационных блоков" Да и вся статья будет интересна

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое, как прочту, то отпишусь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы еще не видели "Примеры создания меню" от Битрикс, пройдите по [ссылке](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=3498&LESSON_PATH=3913.4564.4949.4708.3498)

Там есть примеры создания меню из разделов инфоблоков.